# Getting an object value from props chain call

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have an object

```
const obj = {
key1:{
    key2:{
        val:'value'
    }
}
```

}

Also I have some function that returns the path to the proper value:

```
func(obj,'value') //returns  a string ['key1']['key2']['val']
```

I would like to get the 'value' with a call kind of this:

```
obj`${func(obj,'value')}`
```

It should look like

**obj.key1.key2.val**

But I am getting en error.

The Complexity of this stuff is for pushing the 'value' in an array with saving the tree structure

Comment: There isn't any built-in way to do that in the way you're describing. Have a look at [lenses](https://randycoulman.com/blog/2016/07/12/thinking-in-ramda-lenses/).

Comment: If I understand correct, In this statement `func(obj,'value')`, `value` is a key in deeply nested object and it should return its value. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `reduce()` to return value by iterating an array of keys.

```js
const obj = {key1:{key2:{val:'The retrieved value'}}}

// without eval()
const keyString = "['key1']['key2']['val']";

// return array of keys using regex
const keyReg = /\['(.+?)'\]/g;
const keyArr = [...keyString.matchAll(keyReg)].map(match => match[1]);

// passing obj as inital accumulator and iteratively retrieving nested value
const retrievedValue = keyArr.reduce((a, key) => (a = a[key], a),obj);

console.log(retrievedValue);
```

---

**Using eval()**

This is trivial with [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) but as MDN notes:

> Warning: Executing JavaScript from a string is an enormous security risk. It is far too easy for a bad actor to run arbitrary code when you use eval(). See Never use eval()!, below.

```js
const obj = {key1:{key2:{val:'The retrieved value'}}}

// Simply calling 'eval()' with the string
const keyString = "['key1']['key2']['val']";
const value1 = eval(`obj${keyString}`)

console.log(`obj${keyString}`)
console.log(value1);

// convoluted process to make it look like obj.key1.key2.val
const keyReg = /\['(.+?)'\]/g;
const keyArr = [...keyString.matchAll(keyReg)].map(match => match[1]);
const objQuery = keyArr.reduce((a, key) => (a += `.${key}`, a),`obj`);
const value2 = eval(objQuery)

console.log('');
console.log(objQuery)
console.log(value2);

// if you saved your initial string with a simple delimiter
const delimitedKeyString = "key1/key2/val";
const delimitedQuery = delimitedKeyString.split('/').join('.');
const value3 = eval(`obj.${delimitedQuery}`)

console.log('');
console.log(`obj.${delimitedQuery}`)
console.log(value3);
```